# How to run scripts from multiple virtual environments without activating virtual environments before call?

Tags: python, virtualenv, packaging, package-managers

I forced to have two incompatible versions of python package: more recent version with nice cli and more old version with python API used by third-party orchestration tool which is a python package with cli itself too. Therefore I need to have two separate virtual environments. Also I want to run python interpreter from my current throwaway virtual environment (the third one).

All three commands (package cli, orchestration tool cli and python interpreter) will be called from user and have to be available on the whim without activation/work directory change or other magic spell casted. Also I don't want to dabble with cli script's content so let them be read/run-only for this question purposes.

From my point of view there are a few options to achieve desired behavior.

**A**. add to my `.bash_profile` script line

```
export PATH=venv_throwaway/bin:venv_cli/bin:venv_orchestration_tool/bin:$PATH
```

This solution require manual step for every tool I want to use this way. Also this solution suffers from namespace overlapping issue. `bin` directory for every new cli I want to use this way should be carefully placed strongly after `venv_throwaway/bin` at least because otherwise `new_cli/bin/python` will precede my `venv_throwaway/bin/python` interpreter. Moreover, if some of other CLIs have common dependencies that are incompatible then I have to brute force correct sequence of path placings which is a burden.

**B**. Symlink executable to `/usr/local/bin` for every tool I want to use this way. This solution is almost perfect except it requires manual step.

**B'**. Call cli with full venv path to executable (e.g. `~/.virtualenvs/awscli/bin/aws`). Looks almost like option **B** especially if I will make aliases to shorten venv paths.

**C**. Make my own python package ***my_awesome_cli_installer*** that automatizes manual steps from **B**. Almost perfect except it suffers from [NIH](https://exceptionnotfound.net/not-invented-here-the-daily-software-anti-pattern/) issue.

Is there other way to achieve desired behavior? What option (**A**, **B** or **C**) should I use to?

Comment: Question is how are those invoked: daemons, cronjobs, something else..?

Comment: @AlexanderEjbekov thank you for question. Tools will be called manually from user.  I've updated description.

Comment: With manual calling, wouldn't calling the interpreter binary work? `/opt/venvs/venv1/bin/python script.py`? Also for a bit of usability you could alias the binaries in your `.bashrc` profile so it's `mypyenv1 script.py` and `mypyenv2 script.py` or wrap it in a shell script?

Comment: yes, `venv1/bin/python script.py` will work fine. but those binaries are always a nice entrypoints with shebang and without description, so this way is somehow redundant (pip already place interpreter into script shebang) and a little bit unconvenient (every time someone asks to show me something s/he will bumps into  custom venv paths instead of nice `aws s3 ls` or `ansible-playbook` call).

Comment: @AlexanderEjbekov I've updated description with B' option, thank you!

Comment: > but those binaries are always a nice entrypoints with shebang and without **extension**

Comment: I think the B' option is the most elegant.